# convert a whole string to list when the string is actually a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a very weird problem ...... I have a some lists in my data set which actually became 
strings . Is there anyway to make them list again?

for example I have a string b like

```
In [47]: b    
Out[47]: "['right', 'wrong']"
```

BUT  I want only  ['right', 'wrong'] , How can I do that ?

I tried

```
In [48]:list(b)    
Out[48]: ['[',"'",'r','i','g','h','t',"'",',',' ',"'",'w','r','o','n','g',"'",']']
```

which is normal, because if list is applied to strings ....it separates it. I know it 
but I don't know how to convert them back to lists.

Thanks a lot if anyone can help....

I have also tried join() .....which might be stupid....but i really couldn't figure out 
an easy way. This might be a very stupid question. but thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks a lot I just found the answer in this question

Comment: Try **b.split("\"")**

Comment: A better idea would be to figure out how the list became a string in the first place and prevent it.

Answer (score 5):

I have no idea why you have a list inside a string(doesn't seem like a good idea), but you can use [ast.literal_eval()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to get a list:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "['right', 'wrong']"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
['right', 'wrong']
```

Do note that this will only work for certain things: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and `None`.
But seriously, you shouldn't even want to do this for other kinds of values.

Answer (score 3):

An, easy, stupid way, but fine if you know what you're doing:

```
new_list = eval(b)
```

`eval` will treat the string as an expression, and possibly do some harmful stuff. One can accidentally, or not put a code inside the string, and bam! Your program is a mess. It's also really hard to track errors that is caused by `eval`, and that's why you should avoid it.

There is a safe way though, using `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
new_list = ast.literal_eval(b)
```

which only evaluates it as an object, and you cannot put a code inside it.

A DIY way would be to strip and split it:

```
>>> c = [s.strip(" '") for s in b.strip("[]").split(',')]
>>> c
['right', 'wrong']
```

Comment: You should provide some more information about why using `eval` is a bad decision, and probably avoid using the term "stupid" as that reason.